# Is there a link between brain's energy consumption and human experience?

Tags: brain, neurophysiology, energy-metabolism, learning

I was read the article ([in Scientific American Mind](https://www.scientificamerican.com/article/does-the-brain-use-more-energy-during-particular-activities/))  about energy consumption of brain. There are:

> Say you are learning a new skill—how to juggle or speak Spanish.
>   Neuroscientists have made the fascinating observation that when we do
>   something completely novel, a broad range of brain areas becomes
>   active. As we become more skilled at the task, however, our brain
>   becomes more focused: we require only the essential brain regions and
>   need increasingly less energy to perform that task. Once we have
>   mastered a skill—we become fluent in Spanish—only the brain areas
>   directly involved remain active. Thus, learning a new skill requires
>   more brainpower than a well-practiced activity.

...

> Overall, though, on an individual level, our brain adapts and becomes
>   more efficient as we gain mastery. We build new connections among
>   neurons to keep pace with the greater demand on our neural resources.
>   As our skill level grows in a particular area, our brain will
>   inevitably require less energy to perform that task.

I tried to check what was written there. I tried to find experienced facts that refute or support this article. I did not find anything.

**Question**: are there experimental scientific data that show a decrease in energy consumption by the brain, while doing a certain activity, as professionalism grows? Or maybe there are experimental data that show the opposite? Or is there really no correlation between energy consumption and the growth of professionalism?

Comment: @user1136 Your comment could (should) be an answer. Answering in comments is discouraged in the SE model because it's not possible to both up and downvote your comment, it can't be accepted as an answer, and because comments are meant to be temporary and can be deleted at any time.